# Spring data neo4j aspectJ setup error

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-graph

I can setup spring data and neo4j in STS but I would like to also take advantage of the aspectJ capabilities provided by Spring data.

I have checked and used the Cineasts example as a helper example but it seems that I cannot setup correctly my project, the steps I do are:
Create new maven application.

Add the provided addons on pom.xml.

The problem I am facing is that in every class in my project at the package declaration there is an error that states

> can't determine annotations of missing type javax.persistence.Entity when weaving type com.f.graph.Graph when weaving classes when weaving when 
>    batch building with classpath:

my pom.xml is

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>       4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.neo4j.examples</groupId>
<artifactId>cineasts-aspects</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Cineasts.net Aspects</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.0.0.RC1</spring-security.version>
    <spring-data-neo4j.version>${project.version}</spring-data-neo4j.version>
    <neo4j.version>1.8.M06</neo4j.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.6.12</aspectj.version>
    <env>test</env>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>neo4j-release-repository</id>
      <name>Neo4j Maven 2 release repository</name>
      <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/releases</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>neo4j-snapshot-repository</id>
      <name>Neo4j Maven 2 snapshot repository</name>
      <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/snapshots</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Neo4j Libraries -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.2.v20100523</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
                <!--scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <!-- Must use java 1.5 or higher for annotations -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useFile>true</useFile>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- the eclipse plugin interacts with the aspectj-maven-plugin
        BUT ONLY if the ajdtVersion config value is set (remove it and it won't) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
            <!-- The ajdtVersion configuration parameter is optional. The valid values are none, 1.4, and 1.5. none indicates that AJDT should not be enabled even though Aspectj is enabled in maven. 1.4 generates the org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.prefs file in the .settings directory. 1.5 (or later) includes the configuration into the .classpath file and is the default value. -->
                <ajdtVersion>1.5</ajdtVersion>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am using STS 3.1.0 on windows.
What am I doing wrong?

**===================================== UPDATE =====================================**
I have changed my pom.xml to this one:

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>       4.0.0
>       test
>       myGraph
>       2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
>       jar

```
<name>test.myGraph</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.0.0.RC1</spring-security.version>
    <spring-data-neo4j.version>${project.version}</spring-data-neo4j.version>
    <neo4j.version>1.8.M06</neo4j.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.6.12</aspectj.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
    <env>test</env>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>neo4j-release-repository</id>
      <name>Neo4j Maven 2 release repository</name>
      <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/releases</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>neo4j-snapshot-repository</id>
      <name>Neo4j Maven 2 snapshot repository</name>
      <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/snapshots</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Neo4j Libraries -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.2.v20100523</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
                <!--scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <!-- Must use java 1.5 or higher for annotations -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useFile>true</useFile>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- the eclipse plugin interacts with the aspectj-maven-plugin
        BUT ONLY if the ajdtVersion config value is set (remove it and it won't) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
            <!-- The ajdtVersion configuration parameter is optional. The valid values are none, 1.4, and 1.5. none indicates that AJDT should not be enabled even though Aspectj is enabled in maven. 1.4 generates the org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.prefs file in the .settings directory. 1.5 (or later) includes the configuration into the .classpath file and is the default value. -->
                <ajdtVersion>1.5</ajdtVersion>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

this gives no build errors but when trying to run my main class:

```
public class Graph {

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static void main(String [] args) {       
      ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
      context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Graph-configuration.xml");      
      BeanClass b = (BeanClass)context.getBean("StartBean");
      b.startInsert();
}}
```

I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase] for bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in class path resource [Graph-configuration.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1262)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1331)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:897)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:566)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>       at com.f.graph.Graph.main(Graph.java:35)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>       at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
>       ... 9 more
>   ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
>   JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:838]

Comment: Can you show the code of the `com.f.graph.Graph` referred in the error message (just a snippet including the class declaration and annotations)?

Comment: @remigio added in the update,the code just tries to get a bean from a context.

Comment: Your initial problem was solved?

Comment: @MaksymDemidas No since my initial problem is that I cannot configure spring data to work with aspectj and neo4j

Comment: do you want to use neo4j-server? Then you have to add the dependency: `org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest` to your pom. But for getting started and higher performance I'd recommend using sdn-aspects with an embedded db. Also you shouldn't exclude the jpa-API as it contains (`javax.persistence.Entity`)

Answer (score 1):

Remove this snippet from your pom.xml:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```