# Neo4J Rest Data Graph - using SpringData - connection refused exception

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest

I have a project that use successfully a Neo4J embedded data graph, using SpringData.
I'm trying now to change it to REST database, with no success.

I followed the (simple) instructions and it should have been really easy and straight forward, but I keep getting exceptions on server startup.

I set the server, as in the examples, to `http://localhost:7474/db/data/` and I get 'connection refused' when starting the Tomcat. I would like to mention that currently I'm running this code on my local PC using Eclipse. 
Should I have done something else? install something? create some local libraries? -- because I didn't. I only installed 'Neo4J Community' which I used to view the embedded database.

This is the my application context:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"

        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

        <context:spring-configured />
        <context:annotation-config />

        <!-- NOE4J using Spring DataGraph - for processed data -->
        <!-- REST Connection to Neo4j server -->
        <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />

        <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
            <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/" />
        </bean>

        <!-- Neo4j configuration - Embedded (creates Neo4jTemplate) -->
        <!-- neo4j:config storeDirectory="${db.neo4j.storeDirectory}" /-->

        <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.vo.insight.processed" />

        <context:annotation-config />

<!--Here there are some more Mongo beans...-->

        <!-- Scan components for annotations within the configured package -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.vo.insight.rawdata.entity">
            <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
                expression="org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration" />
        </context:component-scan>

        <tx:annotation-driven />

    </beans>
```

This is the Exception I get when starting Tomcat:

```
2013-12-03 17:02:25,413 ERROR localhost-startStop-1 [@]  - org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'relatedToTopicRelationshipRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingInfrastructure' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.MappingInfrastructureFactoryBean org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingInfrastructure() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingInfrastructure' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.MappingInfrastructureFactoryBean org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingInfrastructure() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingInfrastructure' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.MappingInfrastructureFactoryBean org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingInfrastructure() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingInfrastructure' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.MappingInfrastructureFactoryBean org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingInfrastructure() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:262)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9c18f207.mappingInfrastructure(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate(Neo4jConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9c18f207.CGLIB$neo4jTemplate$28(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9c18f207$$FastClassByCGLIB$$917ec9b3.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9c18f207.neo4jTemplate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.MappingInfrastructureFactoryBean org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingInfrastructure() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springfrDec 03, 2013 5:02:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
```

And finally, I'm using:

- Maven
- Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE
- spring-data-neo4j-rest 2.3.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess this was a foolish question, because the one thing I didn't realize, is that unlike the embedded DB, I should manually start the Neo4 server from the Neo4J community. 
Everything else was fine...